# How to looping taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, loop

is there any way to loop terms in a way they display in menu? 
Eg:

Let say I have 2 taxonomies in a post type - tax1 and tax2.

They are not hierarchical to each other.

If I have posts that have terms like this:

- post 1 => tax1 = p1 ,tax2 = term1
- post 2 => tax1 = p1 ,tax2 = term2
- post 3 => tax1 = p1 ,tax2 = term3
- post 4 => tax1 = p2 ,tax2 = termA
- post 4 => tax1 = p2 ,tax2 = termB
- ......etc

Can I use

```
if(tax1=p1) echo 'term1,term2, term3... in menu/widget'
elseif if(tax1=p2) echo 'termA,termB, termC... in menu/widget'
```

in my template to display the tax2 terms in the sidebar menu?

Somebody might wondering why I don't want to use parent-child terms. Well, this is because I expects have hundreds of term in tax2. If I use hierarchical taxonomy, that will be very long list in single taxonomy. I don't know whether WP able to process them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on a literal menu, you could use `wp_list_pages` possibly to better effect and sort out by certain criteria if you wish, then `foreach` page, display terms. Here is a little function I wrote to spit out terms for a taxonomy passed to it:

```
// give taxonomy, will return link list to custom structure. 
function tax_link_list( $taxonomy ) {
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
if ($terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $term_links = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) { 
        $term_links[] = '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/property-results/?'.$taxonomy.'='.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    }
    $term_space = implode(' ', $term_links);
    return $term_space;
}
}
```

In this example it is returning a list of links for a real estate search engine. You could have it simply return the text. To run this, I pass a taxonomy to the function and get a list of terms. Modified, this might work for you. Check out [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)
as well. Good luck.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, cause I am not so good in coding.  From your codes what I get is full list of terms from the taxonomy (which is tax2, from my example above) that I defined in the function? They will not grouped based on the tax1's term?

Comment: Right. You're going to write that function and edit it's output probably to something more along the lines of (in the `foreach`): `$term_links[] = $term->name;`. When you run the function (in page or wherever), you'll say: `echo tax_link_list($tax1);`